# How do I get a .PFX certificate?

Tags: azure, ssl-certificate, web-hosting

Hi I am trying to connect my azure website to the domain I bought (it is a .dk domain) and I am having trouble finding the the .pfx certificate file I need to upload to my azure website through the portal. What do I need to do exactly? I am lost, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

If you have an Certificate in classic ".crt" Format you can use an online converter like this: https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html

If you have to create an self signed one you do it with OpenSSL

```
openssl req -x509 -days 365 -newkey rsa:<bits> -keyout cert.pem -out cert.pem

openssl pkcs12 -export -in server-cert.pem -inkey cert.pem -out cert.pfx
```

Comment: I used second line for my existing cert + pem set. IMO it will be easier to understand you can rename like `server-cert` to `sslCertificate`, `cert.pem` to `sslCertificatePrivateKey.pem`

Answer (score 0):

1. Generate the CSR file in IIS or the 3rd part tool like **DigiCert**.
2. Use the resulting CSR code to purchase your certificate from providers. In return, they will provide you with a **.CER** file.
3. Export **.PFX** file in tools with the new cert.

Refer to [Obtaining a Certificate for use with Windows Azure Web Sites (WAWS)](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/obtaining-a-certificate-for-use-with-windows-azure-web-sites-waws/) and [Create CSR & Install SLL Certificate](https://www.digicert.com/csr-creation-ssl-installation-windows-azure-website.htm) which would walk you through the steps of how to create the certificate and configure for your Azure website.

Comment: Did you know why the "Yes, export the private key" option is unavailable when we did step 1 and 2?

Comment: @DavidLétourneau it has to be done in the same machine were the CSR was made

Answer (score 0):

The .pfx files contains the public key file (SSL Certificate file) and the associated private key file. Most of SSL certificate provider will give you only SSL Certificate file (public key file). .PFX files are important when you want to transfer your SSL Certificates from one server to another.

You can export your existing certificate as as a .pfx file and import to another server. When you just want to install the SSL Certificate to your domain, just create CSR key from IIS and provide it to your SSL provider, they'll provide you with the Certificate file (.CRT file). You just need to install this certificate to your domain from IIS.